# Pin app to start screen by code

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs, windows-8.1

With Windows 8.1, now the apps are not pinned on the start screen when the user download them.

Is it possible to pin the tile to the start screen from my app's code ? (with a user prompt or not)

If I pin a secondary tile, the user will have two tiles in the app list, that's not what I want. I really want to do the same thing as when the user will go on the app list and manually pin the app to the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pin a secondary tile to the start screen without the user's input.  And the pinned tile goes to the start screen and the app list.  Here is a sample that shows how to do it:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178

and a quickstart article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465443

Comment: I know this about the secondary tiles ; but what I want is to pin the primary tile (with user input, it's ok).